# Increase height of suggestion list in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Something happened to my VSCode and now suggestions list fits only 1 option. How can I adjust its height?

[image: Example]

Comment: Drag the lower border down or use the command `Reset Suggest Widget Size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark)'s comment, you can resize this suggestion tab.

According to the the VS Code [version 1.51 documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_resizable-suggestions), the suggestions tab widget is now resizable.

Hover your mouse pointer on the lower edge of the widget:

[image: Resize 1]

Then, drag your mouse pointer downwards so that the suggestion widget can display more lines:

[image: Resize 2]